# Using array to fill dynamic dropdowns

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to do dynamic dropdowns in PHP using a multidimensional array.

My first select box populates correctly, but upon the choice of a Building, I need the 2nd select box to show the corresponding displays (lobby, break room, etc.) for the first choice

Here's the array:

```
$displays = array(
  "Company" => array(
    "Building 1"=>array(
      "Displays"=>array(
        "Lobby",
        "Break Room",
        "Office",
        ),
      ),
    "Building 2"=>array(
      "Displays"=>array(
        "Break Room",
        "Office",
        ),
      ),
    "Building 3"=>array(
      "Displays"=>array(
        "Lobby",
        "Break Room",
        ),
      ),
    "Building 4"=>array(
      "Displays"=>array(
        "Lobby",
        "Break Room",
        "Office"
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

And my two select boxes as of now:

```
/*This select option works to fill the list with building 1 through building 4, as it should*/
<select class="form-control" id="plantSelect">
    <?php foreach($displays["Company"] as $area_name => $area_details): ;?>
    <option><?php echo $area_name ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>

/*I need this one to show the displays (lobby, break room, office, etc.) for each builing as it's selected*/
<select class="form-control" id="areaSelect">
    <?php foreach($displays["Company"] as $area_name => $area_details): ;?>
    <option><?php echo $area_details?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

And my incomplete jquery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#plantSelect").change(function() {
     $("#areaSelect").load("/*don't know what to put here*/" + $("#plantSelect").val());
    });
</script>
```

Any help to finish this up is much appreciated

Comment: json_encode the array ad have it live in the page as a JS object

Comment: `/*don't know what to put here*/` - at this point, perhaps some research and attempts are in order? With your rep, you know we are here to help you, but to help fix your issues, not to write it for you

Comment: @SamSwift웃 right, I'm not asking for anyone to write it. I've used research and attempts to get to this point, but I'm having a hard time finding guidance that isn't based on a JSON object. Just looking for some guidance rather than someone writing it for me

Comment: @TomN. - the point here is, you've asked a question (fair enough), but you haven't shown research or attempts, instead you've explicitly said in the code; `/*don't know what to put here*/`, which are vital, you've received an answer which worked for you, glad you have, but we need to see what you've got, even if someone writes up something different. We are here to help fix what's broken - instead, you've had the code written for you

Comment: @SamSwift웃 yeah, I totally understand your point there. I usually post code that isn't working properly with things I've tried and hope for course correction. I guess here I just hit a brick wall on how far to go. I'll totally take those points into consideration for the future though, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

json_encode the array and have it live in the page as a JS object

```js
var Company = {
  "Building 1": [{
    "Displays": [
      "Lobby",
      "Break Room",
      "Office"
    ]
  }],
  "Building 2": [{
    "Displays": [
      "Break Room",
      "Office"
    ]
  }],
  "Building 3": [{
    "Displays": [
      "Lobby",
      "Break Room"
    ]
  }],
  "Building 4": [{
    "Displays": [
      "Lobby",
      "Break Room",
      "Office"
    ]
  }]
};

$.each(Company, function(bld) {
  $("#plantSelect").append('<option value="' + bld + '">' + bld + '</option>')
});
$("#plantSelect").on("change", function() {
  $("#areaSelect")[0].length=1;
  if (this.value) {
    $.each(Company[this.value][0].Displays,function(_,disp) {
      $("#areaSelect").append('<option value="' + disp + '">' + disp + '</option>')
    });
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="plantSelect">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="areaSelect">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to strictly manipulate the array, but I actually really like this option. I'm going to work with it now, thank you!

Comment: This works perfect now, Thanks! In the future when I have the array coming from a database select, I'm assuming I could go into my script and do something like var company = json_encode($displays) assuming that $displays is the database result, right?

Comment: Yes `var Companys = <?php echo json_encode($displays => Company); ?>; ` or however you get the companys level in php